# How can I delete FileSearchActivity records?

Tags: delete, global-search

I was looking through the list of tables in SoqlXplorer, as I do every so often (I find it a useful way to learn things), and I came across a table called `FileSearchActivity`.

What is this table?

It looks like that table is an index of all search bar searches in my org since 2016-Feb (just under 3 years ago), who did it, and how many hits there were.

Do I have any control over its contents?  Can I control its retention?

It would be great if I had some control over how long we retain these records.  Can I delete them somehow?  (I can't do it manually as a SysAdmin).  Will they continue to accumulate forever or is three years the max?  Is this something I can get in touch with my rep about?

There is also a similarly-named table called `SearchActivity` which is empty.  What to make of that?

For reference, the fields on this table are:

- AvgNumResults
- ClickRank
- CountQueries
- CountUsers
- CreatedById
- CreatedDate
- Id
- IsDeleted
- LastModifiedById
- LastModifiedDate
- Name
- Period
- QueryDate
- QueryLanguage
- SearchTerm
- SystemModstamp